# Handling curly braces in curl/libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

From the command line, I have a curl request with two query parameters that use curly braces. However, one only works when URL-encoded and the other only works when it is **not** URL-encoded.

Here's an example of a request that (weirdly) works from the command line and returns data for 3 IDs. I wouldn't expect it to work because `TIME` is URL-encoded with curly braces (`%7B` and `%7D`) but `P_ID` is not:

1. `curl -X GET "https://example.com/search?TIME=%7B%22TIME_TYPE%22%3A%22MESSAGE%22%2C%22MESSAGENUMBER%22%3A5%7D&P_ID={1,2,3}"`

Even weirder, the following calls don't work and seem to ignore the `P_ID` field and give me data for every person:

2. `curl -X GET "https://example.com/search?TIME=%7B%22TIME_TYPE%22%3A%22MESSAGE%22%2C%22MESSAGENUMBER%22%3A5%7D&P_ID=%7B1,2,3%7D"`
3. `curl -X GET "https://example.com/search?TIME=%7B%22TIME_TYPE%22%3A%22MESSAGE%22%2C%22MESSAGENUMBER%22%3A5%7D&P_ID=1&P_ID=2&P_ID=3"`
4. `curl -X GET "https://example.com/search?TIME={%22TIME_TYPE%22%3A%22MESSAGE%22%2C%22MESSAGENUMBER%22%3A5}&P_ID=1&P_ID=2&P_ID=3"`

Given these constraints, where the first call works as I want it to, but the second and third do not, then how do I use libcurl in C++ such that the first call is replicated? I know [`CURLOPT_URL`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) encodes everything, so it would encode both the braces in `TIME` and `P_ID`. I've tried using `CURLUPART` like below, but to no avail.

```
void *curlHandle;
curl_easy_reset(curlHandle);
CURLU *url = curl_url();
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_URL, "example.com", 0);
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_QUERY, "P_ID={1,2,3}", CURLU_APPENDQUERY);
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_QUERY, "TIME=%7B%22TIME_TYPE%22%3A%22MESSAGE%22%2C%22MESSAGENUMBER%22%3A5%7D", CURLU_APPENDQUERY);
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_SCHEME, "https", 0);
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_PATH, "/search/", 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_CURLU, url);
curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
```

I'm getting this response:

> * No URL set
> Curl failed with error 3: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL. 0 retries remaining

In summary: how do I get libcurl to make a bizarre curl request like the first one up top? Because that is the only way I can execute from the command line with the expected result of only getting the 3 people's data.

Alternatively, is there perhaps another way to try this curl request other than the 4 attempts above? Should I just reach out to the API owner and ask why it likes `{` encoded in some places and not others?

Comment: CURLOPT_URL does not encode anything, I can't see why that first URL won't just work as-is. It doesn't work for the command line tool because it "globs" on the braces, so you need to switch that off with -g and then the tool should accept that UR L as well. AFAICS.

Comment: All command examples do not have closing " and have invalid URLs `https:example.com`. Is it intentional?

Comment: @273K No that was not intentional, sorry for that! Just fixed.

Comment: @DanielStenberg when I run with CURLOPT_VERBOSE, the output is telling me it's converting every brace to %7D/%7B. From what I've seen online adding -g would help, but I'm not sure how to do that with libcurl? Can't find documentation on adding -g

Comment: The commands still cannot run due to unclosed ". How can we help you if we don't know what you do execatly.

Comment: `curl -X GET "https://httpbin.org/get?TIME=%7B%22TIME_TYPE%22%3A%22MESSAGE%22%2C%22MESSAGENUMBER%22%3A5%7D&P_ID=%7B1,2,3%7D" -H "accept: application/json"` works well. The error may be in your server. BTW if `{1,2,3}` is supposed to be JSON like `TIME` is, it's an invalid JSON. You might want `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @273K Sorry, I can't provide the exact API for security reasons, I closed the quotes. TIME_TYPE is meant to be a JSON but P_ID typically takes a single integer ID except it works for multiple integer IDs when you do {x,y,z}. The help I need is how to get libcurl to URL encode one query (TIME_TYPE) but not URL encode another (P_ID). I also should mention that it errors out with brackets [], so the only curl command I do that works as expected and returns 3 people's data is the first one in my question. I just can't figure out how to exactly pass that through libcurl

Comment: `CURLOPT_URL` does not encode anything. `{` and `}` are not escape chars, see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/planning-analytics/2.0.0?topic=api-using-url-escape-characters-url. The issue is somewhere but not in curl. If you can't provide exact requests, why do you ask us to help? Ask your colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are your 4 query strings after being url decoded.

```
TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID={1,2,3}
TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID={1,2,3}
TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID=1&P_ID=2&P_ID=3
TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID=1&P_ID=2&P_ID=3
```

None of the characters in your query strings need to be urlencoded.
Given you basically have two urls. 
These are both urls, and the query strings url decoded on the server:

```
https://example.com?TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID=1&P_ID=2&P_ID=3
TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID=1&P_ID=2&P_ID=3


https://example.com?TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID={1,2,3}
TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID={1,2,3}
```

I do not think your query string is causing the error.
It appears you got this wrong:

```
CURLU *url = curl_url();
```

Maybe it should be:

```
CURLU *url= curl_url();
curl_url_set(url, CURLUPART_URL,
R"(https://example.com?TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID={1,2,3})", 0);
```

Or just pass the URL directly to the easy handle:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, R"(https://example.com?TIME={"TIME_TYPE":"MESSAGE","MESSAGENUMBER":5}&P_ID={1,2,3})");
```